# Finding the largest number in a .txt file containing html code

Tags: java, html

The code should read a .txt file containing html code, Then find numbers between the code provided and print out the largest number of the three pieces of code. The larges number should be 42.25. Thanks in advance.

```
// 1.) <span class="green">24.52&nbsp;▲&nbsp;0.96%</span></td>
// 2.) <span class="green">0.68&nbsp;▲&nbsp;0.41%</span></td>
// 3.) <span class="green">42.25&nbsp;▲&nbsp;0.36%</span></td>

    // need to print out 42.25 as the largest number of the three above

public class LargestNumber {

    public static void name() {

        // this is the pattern before the name
        String patternBeforeName = "<td><a href=\"http://www.nasdaq.com/aspx/infoquotes.aspx?symbol=";

        // this is the pattern after the name
        String patternAfterName = "&amp;selected=";
        String bigText = IOMaster.readTextFile("Project1.txt");
        String patternBeforeValuePosative = "<td><span class=\"green\">";

        int indexOfBeginning = bigText.indexOf(patternBeforeValuePosative);

        while (indexOfBeginning >= 0) { // check if found)

            int indexOfEnd = bigText.indexOf(patternAfterName, indexOfBeginning); // start looking from the indexOfBeginning
            if (indexOfEnd >= 0) { // check if found
                String index = bigText.substring(indexOfBeginning + patternBeforeName.length(), indexOfEnd);

                // splits the text between the html tags </a></d>
                String[] indexList = index.split("</a></td>");

                // for statement
                for (int i = 0; i < indexList.length; i++) {
                    index = indexList[i];

                    // currently prints out 24.52
                    System.out.println("The name is:\t\t" + index);
                }
            }
            bigText = bigText.substring(indexOfEnd);
            indexOfBeginning = bigText.indexOf(patternBeforeName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This back-to-school season is the time of year when we at Stack Overflow want to remind you that **we don't do people's homework here**.  [An open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all digits in your text using a regex. Everything you need to do after that is find the maximum.

```
public static List<Double> findNumbers(String bigText) {
    List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+.[0-9]*|[0-9]*.[0-9]+|[0-9]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(bigText);
    while (m.find()) {
        numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(m.group());
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

And then you can find the Maximum pretty easy:

```
public double findMaximum(List<Double> numbers) {
    double max = 0.0;
    for(double d: numbers) {
        if(d > max) max = d;
    }
    return max;
}
```